# Destructuring and Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm doing some basic destructuring in Javascript:

```
//@flow
"use strict";

(function(){
    const {a,c} = check(true);
})();


function check(bool:boolean):{|a:string,c:string|}|{||}{
  if(bool){
    return { 
      a:"b",
      c:"d"
    };

  }
  else{
    return Object.freeze({});
  }
}
```

But Flow gives me errors.

```
5:  const {a,c} = check(true);
           ^ property `a`. Property not found in
9: function check(bool:boolean):{|a:string,c:string|}|{||}{
                                                  ^ object type
5:  const {a,c} = check(true);
             ^ property `c`. Property not found in
9: function check(bool:boolean):{|a:string,c:string|}|{||}{
                                                      ^ object type
```

[web compiler link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTACDMBsHsHcCgBEBXAzgUwASoC4CcBLAYx0QG554AKcZAOxIOjqoEoBveASCOd03YBDADREAvpgC8mIgAt0RANZV8ydKwpjWbCpVoMcTOjPlKqAI2jRIALkvX0guqxvsAPoJu5CdAOaivfAI-NzE3d1DOLgJwCytIDnhMZJS8dBxkPGN2TCSU-M9Ec0RhPPzkohtEABNEMpSxCnKU+rF69EgMTma0jKzMAHlzACsFHAA6cDT0AC90KnYtJob4MSA)

What is Flow looking for, and how can I solve it?

Comment: This is kind of a link only question. Please add the code right here.

Comment: It is actually good that flow complains, because your types are wrong. `check` has the potential to be called with `false` leading to `const {a,c} = {}`. This is a type error indicated by `a`/`c` as being `undefined`. Besides I think you don't need exact object types in this case.

Comment: @ftor. I don't completely agree. I think the error is misplaced. I think this should be valid, but if I called `function foo(a:string){}` it should warn me that I may be passing a null.

Answer (score 2):

Signature of check() is not {a: string, c: string}
I edited your code to respect this type and it worked.

```
//@flow
"use strict";

(function(){
    const {a,c} = check(true);
})();


function check(bool:boolean):{|a:string,c:string|}{
   if(bool){
      return { 
         a:"b",
         c:"d"
      };

   } else{
     return Object.freeze({a: "", c: ""});
   }
}
```

You didn't tell your specific use case so feel free to comment if this solution is not working for you.

Comment: Interesting. What if `a` & `c` were numbers or booleans? Returning 0 or false wouldn't be accurate. I'd much rather return an empty object, and check if a/c were `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function return type as of now can be an empty object or of the form `{a: string, b: string}`

```
function check(bool:boolean):{|a:string,c:string|}|{||}{
```

Actually "|" stands for OR so in your case your function return type is either `{|a: string, C: string|}` OR `{|}`

See: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/

And then when you destructure it in this function

```
const {a,c} = check(true);
```

It's trying to access the properties `a` and `c` in an empty object so the flow is showing this warning, because check function can also return empty object.

### Solution:

provide some initial default value to your variables a and c so that if they don't exist still they could be initialised

```
(function(){
    const {a='',c=''} = check(true);
})();
```